# warning C4267: 'initializing' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'UINT'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am upgrading my application to 64-bit platform in VS2010.
I want to resolve below warning, what is correct way to do it? I dont want to change data type of MyVar because this variable is used as an argument in many functions. If I want to type cast output of "strlen( Mystring)" to const int then how to do.

```
const int aSel = 40;
UINT MyVar= aSel - strlen( Mystring );//Warning C4267
```

Comment: Most compilers keep `int` as a 32-bit value even on 64-bit systems. It's most likely that the actual type `size_t` is an alias of is a type that is 64 bits on a 64-bit system and 32 bits on a 32-bit system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a variety of choices:

1. Ignore the warning globally - I really do not recommend this one.  At some point you will encounter a 4GB+1 "thing", assign to `UINT`, and truncate.
2. Ignore the warning on this particular line with a comment as to why this is safe.  That's a bit of a code smell to me, and pretty noisy, and not portable.
3. Change the type of `MyVar`.  You say you don't want to do that.  In this particular case this is reasonable, but with hindsight `MyVar` should almost certainly have been declared as `size_t`.
4. Static cast:  `auto MyVar = static_cast<UINT>(aSel - strelen(MyString));`.

I think I prefer changing the type of `MyVar`, but if that really is too much work, then static_cast is probably the best.  (Don't use a c-style cast - you want to be explicit that you are doing static_cast not reinterpret_cast.)

Answer (score 0):

`size_t` is 64bits in most 64bit compiler implementations. so you better use `size_t` type instead of `UINT`. This way it will be safe on both 32bit and 64bit systems.

Comment: If you're going to change the type at all, why use `UINT64` and not just `size_t`? There's no point in forcing 32-bit compilations to use 64-bit types if there are no sizes that require 64-bit types. Anyway, the OP doesn't want to change the type. If you disagree with the OP's choice, then at the very least you should explain why.